# Angular (2+) : how can i know from parent component when all child-components were initialized?

Tags: angular, children, lifecycle-hook

is there a lifecycle hook so-called "ngAfterAllChildrenInit" because ngAfterViewInit is called before ngOninit of the children,

I am trying to avoid hacking with setTimeOut or emitting events from all the children and collecting them and then do what I want ( that depend on the children initialization)

it seems so common why is it not part of angular?

Answer (score 1):

You could use decorators for that. I mean, Angular decorators, not custom ones.

In your parent :

```
activated: any = {};
```

In your children :

```js
constructor(@Host() parent: ParentComponent) {}

// Hook of your choice
ngOnInit() { this.parent.activated[this.constructor.name] = true; }
```

This will create an `activated` object like this

```js
activated = {
  FirstChildComponent: true
  // Second not initialized ? Then not here and activated[SecondChildComponent] = undefined
};
```

Comment: And how do you catch the event when all the components were initialized ?

Comment: You count how many children you have, and when `Object.keys(this.activated)` reaches it, then you make the event. Need help for that ?

Comment: I am not the OP ^^ I am just curious about how to do that.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'm user agnostic :P Do you want me to make an edit to my post to expose an example ?

Comment: No No, I am sure that there's an easier way to do that

Comment: Well, feel free to post an answer then !

Answer (score 0):

Angular Lifecycle hooks are very powerful, in order to achieve what you want, you can simply use the OnInit lifecycle hook. Angular is reading your template file and running your component in a vertical way (from top to down). So, you just have to do whatever you want in your last component's ngOnInit method.

If your components are used in different parts of your application, you can check that the parent component is the one you want by using the @Host decorator (see the answer of @trichetriche).

I created a stack blitz where there's 3 components used in the app component (parent) in this order:

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<app-child></app-child>
```

So the AppComponent OnInit hook will fire first, and after that the HelloComponent OnInit and finally the ChildComponent.

See it in action on the console: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-62xjux

**EDIT:** You can use the `ngAfterViewChecked` as the documentation specifies:

> Respond after Angular checks the component's views and child views /
>   the view that a directive is in.
>
> Called after the ngAfterViewInit and every subsequent
>   ngAfterContentChecked().

Comment: This is a very contextual answer. Your exampl works because your components are useless : they contain no code, no logic, nothing. What happens if there is a huge component, and a very tiny one ? They won't launch in the same order. You can't rely on the fact that they will be launched one after the other, this is too fragile !

Comment: This is only intialization ! You can use another lifecycle hook if you want to be sure that the components has rendered, for example `ngAfterViewChecked`

Comment: Same argument applies. If one has a much bigger view and the other has just a div, nothing guarantees the order.

Comment: I tried, ngAfterViewChecked gets fired every time Angular checks the view if it needs updates. So it gets fired very often, and after a few cycles it also runs into the view update error

Answer (score 0):

how about use a service. the last child publish an event through observable, and the parent subscribes to it.